# Azure functions: Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

Trying to run this Azure Function in Azure portal but fails with above title error:

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public static string Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        string name="dbconn";
        string conStr = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(conStr)) // Azure Functions App Service naming convention
            conStr = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"SQLCONNSTR_{name}", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                conn.Open();

            }
        return conStr;
```

I've added in the AzureSQL database ADO.NET ConnectionString:
[image]
Google search shows this issue mostly happening for local in regards to System.Data.SqlClient. But the issue I have is at host in azure's portal, i'm not publishing from VS, so not sure how to fix this. Help really appreciated.

In case I also tried to change System.Data.SqlClient for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient but can't compile: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

In Azure cli I can see .net core is v 2.2.402 and not sure if updating to 3.1 could this be the issue? I can update to .Net Core 3.1 on windows 10 pc but Azure cli continues to show .net core 2.2.402. I posted question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60514333/how-install-net-core-in-azure-cli-share-folder) question how to also update the azure environment.

Thanks a bunch for your help, cheers!

Comment: Is your function deploy from vs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something is wrong with the connection string. Please check that you are you using something similar to this:

```
Server=tcp:{your_server}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={your_database};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_user};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

For what concern using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, which is the recommended library, you need to add it to the solution first:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Net.SqlClient
```

Comment: Btw, a fully working sample of Azure SQL and Azure Function is here: https://github.com/yorek/azure-sql-hyperscale-autoscaler

Comment: thanks @mauridb , yes connection string meets pattern you showed above. In regards to dotnet command, I execute in Azure cli and get error Could not find any project in `/home/sergio/`. I then tried in the kudu's function CMD  D:\home\site\wwwroot>cd FunctionName and D:\home\site\wwwroot but still get Could not find any project in `path'. What may i be doing wrong?

Comment: I tried the git example you posted, deployment directly to portal gives error The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1. [D:\home\site\repository\Autoscaler.csproj] . However my dotnet --info shows .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json): Version:   2.2.402. can only be run from VS?

Comment: Not sure what's happening on your side..I just tried to deploy it again, using VS Code directly (with the Azure Function extension) and it is working nicely. Could be that you need to update your local SDK in order to compile it. Make sure you installed .NET Core SDK 3.1: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Comment: thanks a bunch @mauridb , I've used your project settings and can now avoid this error message. I also find the project you kindly linked very helpful for sql routines :)

Comment: However, I can connect with a broken down connectionstring in the script (string serverName = "myservername"; string uid = "myadminname"; string pwd = "myadminpasswd"; string mycatalogue = "mydbname"; string connectionString = $"Server=tcp:{serverName}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={mycatalogue};User ID={uid};Password={pwd};";) but when I use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureSQLConnection"); updated for my connection string it fails to connect. I can connect with MSSMS from same IP no problem. any ideas please?

Comment: Make sure you have "AzureSQLConnection" in the Azure Function Application Settings

Comment: OMG what an idiot, i wasn't removing the {} in the pwd for the app settings in VS lol, thanks a bunch for your help!